# python eve distinct values

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

Trying to set a static filter in python eve using Mongodb.
I am looking to return a list of distinct categories based on a content collection.

```
category = {
  'datasource': {
     'source': 'content',
     #'filter': {'category': {'$distinct': True} },
     'projection': {'category': 1},
    }
}
```

The above is causing an error (when the filter line is commented out). 
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the error?

Comment: Its just a standard 500 Internal server error when the category endpoint is requested. I am guessing the $distinct value is not valid (it was nothing more than a guess as to the allowed values;)

Answer (score 0):

If you run your Eve application in debug mode (`app.run(Debug=True`), or set `DEBUG = True` in your settings file, you will get to see what the actual error is:

`OperationFailure: database error: invalid operator: $distinct`

MongoDB [distinct](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/distinct/) is an Aggregation Framework command, not a query operator like, for example, `$exists` (which in fact you can use to set up a Eve static filter).

Comment: Thanks for the debug tip Nicola. I did in fact use the example in the docs where $exists was given as an example, but do realise that I am was not looking for a query operator. I included it above to help illustrate what I was trying to achieve. Any pointers in how I return a distinct data set using eve though? (thanks for a great framework btw ;)